# Why is my Android app force-closing from a java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError, and it's not being caught by the try/catch block?

Tags: android, exception, reflection

I'm using reflection to see if the Equalizer class is available for Android OS 2.3 and higher, and then use that class if it is available. However, I'm periodically getting crash reports with the "ExceptionInInitializerError". Here are the stacktrace:

```
java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:234)
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:181)
at com.myapp.EQ.<init>(SourceFile:16)
at com.myapp.mainAct.onCreate(SourceFile:209)
at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1615)
at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1667)
at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:117)
at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:935)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3687)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:842)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: Cannot load library: reloc_library[1312]: 277 cannot locate '_ZN7android11AudioEffect25queryDefaultPreProcessingEiP19effect_descriptor_sPj'...

at java.lang.Runtime.loadLibrary(Runtime.java:455)
at java.lang.System.loadLibrary(System.java:554)
at android.media.audiofx.AudioEffect.<clinit>(AudioEffect.java:63)
```

And here's the custom class where the error is getting thrown:

```
public class EQ{
    private Class<?> eqClass = null;

    public EQ(){
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= 9){
            try {
                eqClass = Class.forName("android.media.audiofx.Equalizer"); 
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

So, the crash happens at the "Class.forName" line, and any exception should be caught by the `Catch` block. Why isn't it?

This happens sporadically, and I've received 5 different crash reports over the last 2 months.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError` is not an `Exception` and thus can't be caught using your `try catch` block.

[The java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/lang/ExceptionInInitializerError.html) say its a child of `Error`

Instead try catching that **specifc type of error** like this:

```
catch (java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError er)
```

Comment: OK, so is there no way for me to prvent a force-close?

Comment: `catch(ExceptionInInitializerError e)`

Comment: **No** don't catch `Throwable t` that is WAY to generic. When catching errors you really should only catch the specific error that you predict will occur.  If a different error occurs for a unkown reason you can't assume that everything is ok catch it anyway.

Comment: @slayton I know, was making a (bad) joke.

Comment: Duh... I must have had a brain fart thinking that catching an Exception would catch every throwable! Thanks